# How can i run 2 different M-files parallel in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I have 2 different M-files and want to run them in parallel in MATLAB 
and also show the plots simultaneously in different screens.

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution: launch the program twice.

Hard solution, provided you have the Parallel toolbox: [`spmd`](http://mathworks.com/help/distcomp/spmd.html)

```
spmd
if labindex == 1
    program1
elseif labindex ==2
    program2
end
```

Comment: FYI, your simple solution is less simple on OS X where applications are single instance by default. There are [ways around this](http://superuser.com/questions/312439/open-two-instances-of-the-same-app-on-mac-os-x) however.